# QListWidget on click check item type

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget + click action logic like:

```
class CustomListWidget(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, "Custom text")

    def custom_method(self, qWidget):
        # do something
```

```
# self is QWindow
self.myListWidget1 = QListWidget()

l1 = CustomListWidget()
l2 = QListWidgetItem("Test")

self.myListWidget1.insertItem(1, l1)
self.myListWidget1.insertItem(1, l2)

self.myListWidget1.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClicked)

# [....]

def onItemClicked(self, item): 
    item.__class__ = CustomListWidget
    item.custom_method(self)
```

My issue is that inside `onItemClicked` the `item` is always `QListWidgetItem` and I can not separate by type. Is there any way to get/check the class of the item, so that I can cast or just use the custom method if the item was instantiated as `CustomListWidget` or not?

For example, this won't work before l1 will be ok with the cast toward `CustomListWidget` but I can't/don't want to do the same for l2

Comment: use `if isinstance(item, CustomListWidget):`